# Xcode: change Object from Exit to View Controller

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode11, xcode11.3

I have an issue when I dragging and dropping from Assistant Editor to code button that button has automatically set **Object** to **Exit** but I need to set to **View Controller**. The issue is in the picture below. Is there any solution to solve it?

[Issue in xCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5p4y.png)

Comment: Unclear what you did to generate that screen shot. On my machine, the Exit listing is a popup menu that you can click to change it to View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in two ways. When you are in the storyboard/xib screen the easiest approach is to hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and at the same time select and drag from button to the assistant view. Do it like below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: you have in **Object** section **File's owner** I have there **Exit** how can I change it?

Comment: Where you put your button? Are you put it in the parent view like me?